# Bootstrap classes causing input element to move to next line

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I add the classes `has-error` and `has-success` to the closest div, why does it make the input element `#confirmPassword` move to the next line?

HTML -

```
<form method = "post" action = "" ng-controller = "resettingCtrl as reset">

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="reset.password">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Confirm</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="reset.confirmPassword">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

JS-

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Att1App')
    .controller('resettingCtrl', resettingCtrl);

  function resettingCtrl() {   
    var self = this;

    self.pass = "";
    self.confirmPass = "";

    angular.element(document.getElementById("confirmPassword")).on("input", function () {

        if(self.pass != document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value) {

                var div1 = document.getElementById('confirmPassword').closest('div');
                //div1.className = "has-error";
                return false;
            }

            else {

                var div2 = document.getElementById('confirmPassword').closest('div');
                div2.className = "has-success";
                return true; 
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to add the `has-success` class to the `div` in this way:

```
var div2 = document.getElementById('confirmPassword').closest('div');
div2.className = "has-success";
```

You delete the previous `div` classes. In this case it loses the `col-sm-10` class which was responsible for its width and that's why the input grows bigger and moves to the next line

Change your code to:

```
var div2 = document.getElementById('confirmPassword').closest('div');
div2.className += " has-success";
```

***Or*** use jQuery if you load it:

```
$("#confirmPassword").closest('div').addClass("has-success");
```

Both approaches will add the new class to the div but will also preserve the existing classes.